# My bookmarklet opens a new window, if the window is already open I want to call .focus()

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, window.open

I have a bookmarklet that opens up a new window:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open(
        'http://localhost:8080/myapp/query.jsp?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'t='+encodeURIComponent(document.title),
        'query','status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=false,scrollbars=false,height=600,width=410'
        ));query.focus();">MyApp</a>
```

When the window is not open, this works fine as it gets opened and is visible.

But if the window was already open and I click the bookmarklet, I want the existing window to be made in focus and have the new data that is submitted be processed (if the page is different).

You can see I have tried to do this with `query.focus();` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Call `focus()` on the window returned by `window.open()`:

```
window.open(url, name, params).focus();
```